# How can I access a new window when test is running using cypress

Tags: cypress, ui-automation

I want to visit an url perform some operations then open different url in different tab/window and perform some action in new tab and come back to the previous tab/window and so on. Is this possible in cypress?
Please suggest some solution if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Cypress does not and will not support handling more than one tab/browser, for further read and recipes see: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs.html#Multiple-tabs

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions:

1. Use api request for the operations needed for the external url
2. Divide the test in different cases
   2.1. In before/beforeEach section make preparations needed
   2.2. It case for first part in your project
   2.3. It case for the different url
   2.4. It case for the second part needed in your project

If have some repetitive data that needs to be reused - you can declare it as a variable ouside of the "describe" scope with usual JS code.

Comment: But the second url will open in the same tab, i want to open the second url in different tab/window and switch between them

Comment: Cypress literally doesn`t allow it